# Is there a way to customize "Programmable Completion" in the current session?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

If I start typing a command or filename, I can use the tab key to auto-complete my string.  Is there a way to change the auto-complete behavior for the current bash session?

#### For example

On pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the current session, only files that contain `*.txt` will be displayed.

How does the autocomplete function work?  Is there a set of environment variables or something that can be adjusted to change the autocomplete behavior?

Comment: This might be a good starting point for you. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion

Comment: I think you can do this for a particular command in bash (`complete -X PATTERN`) but not for all commands in one go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the `bash_completion` mechanism it's the bash function `_filedir_xspec()` that is responsible for filename and dirname completions. This funtion can be found in the script `/etc/bash_completion`.

You can edit that function and add a line that contains your regex. For example use this function (it's a copy of the original function):

```
_filedir_xspec()
{
    local IFS cur xspec

    IFS=$'\n'
    COMPREPLY=()
    _get_comp_words_by_ref cur

    _expand || return 0

    # get first exclusion compspec that matches this command
    xspec=$( awk "/^complete[ \t]+.*[ \t]${1##*/}([ \t]|\$)/ { print \$0; exit }" \
        "$BASH_COMPLETION" )
    # prune to leave nothing but the -X spec
    xspec=${xspec#*-X }
    xspec=${xspec%% *}

    local -a toks
    local tmp

    toks=( ${toks[@]-} $(
        compgen -d -- "$(quote_readline "$cur")" | {
        while read -r tmp; do
            # see long TODO comment in _filedir() --David
            printf '%s\n' $tmp
        done
        }
        ))

    # Munge xspec to contain uppercase version too
    eval xspec="${xspec}"
    eval xspec="!*.txt" #<---- HERE add your regex, that's the only line changed
    local matchop=!
    if [[ $xspec == !* ]]; then
        xspec=${xspec#!}
        matchop=@
    fi
    [[ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -ge 4 ]] && \
        xspec="$matchop($xspec|${xspec^^})" || \
        xspec="$matchop($xspec|$(printf %s $xspec | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'))"

    toks=( ${toks[@]-} $(
        eval compgen -f -X "!$xspec" -- "\$(quote_readline "\$cur")" | {
        while read -r tmp; do
            [ -n $tmp ] && printf '%s\n' $tmp
        done
        }
        ))
    [ ${#toks[@]} -ne 0 ] && _compopt_o_filenames
    COMPREPLY=( "${toks[@]}" )
}
```

Notice the new part at **line 32**:

```
eval xspec="!*.txt"
```

This statement is later used in `compgen` to remove all entries, that do not match the regular expression. I wouldn't recommend to edit the file `/etc/bash_completion`. Instead make a new file with the content above and `source` the file if needed:

```
source /path/to/file
```

Now, all commands/applications in the shell, that where completed by the function  `_filedir_xspec()`, complete now only with `*.txt` filenames.

Comment: Cool... What about making it only be for the current session?

Comment: it IS only for the current session. You can copy the function into your shell and it will be away in the next session. But I recommend to source a file that contains the function when you need it. In the next session it's not anymore available. To make it permanent, I would write it one of the rc scripts: `~/.bashrc` for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this only for certain programs, or your custom script or command.

For showing only files that have the `txt` extension in the suggestion, simply write a shell script and `source` in the current session:

```
# Autocomplete file /path/to/file/sample-completion.sh
# for the command `sample`
_sample(){
   COMPREPLY=($(compgen -f -X "!.*[.][tT][xX][tT]$" -- "$2"))
}

complete -F _sample sample
```

And source it by calling:

```
$ source /path/to/file/sample-completion.sh
```

In this code, `$2` is the current word being completed. The `-- "$2"` part makes [`compgen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) filter out only the suggestions that contain the current word being completed and put it into [`COMPREPLY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-COMPREPLY). Also, the `-f` option tells [`compgen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) to only look for files in the current directory. Last but not least the `-X` option is a [filter pattern (look here)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) that excludes [matching file names](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html). The `!` in the beginning of pattern **negates** this behavior. As a result, only the files with `.txt` extension will be shown. The `$` sign at the end of the regex looks for matches that end with given pattern. The `[.]` means it will look for a literal dot, not just any character - which is the default meaning of a dot in regex. The `[tT][xX][tT]` part means the pattern will match all these situations: "txt, txT, tXt, tXT, Txt, TxT, TXT, TXt".

Answer (score 0):

Leaning on the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136405/127903) from @chaos, I propose this function to **patch** the existing completion function when needed:

```
patchFDxspec(){
  . <(type _filedir_xspec | sed -e '1d;s/\(eval xspec="\).*$/&\n\1!*.txt";/');
}
```

Executing this function will patch `_filedir_xspec` for the current session.

If you need other extensions than `.txt`, you could modify the function to take the wanted suffix as `$1`.