# How can autocompletion for PON (PPTP VPN) command be enabled?

Tags: autocomplete

This is my **PPTP** peers config:

```
$ sudo ls -la /etc/ppp/peers/
total 24
drwxr-s--- 2 root dip  4096 Oct 14 00:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root dip  4096 Oct 14 00:18 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root dip   172 Oct 14 00:20 Themiscyra
-rw-r----- 1 root dip  1093 Jan 29  2016 provider
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   30 Dec 25  2015 wvdial
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   75 Dec 25  2015 wvdial-pipe
```

When testing connection to `Themiscyra`, I do:

```
$ sudo pon Them
```

... and now, pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> does not autocomplete the name to `Themiscyra`. But I am sure I **saw** (months ago) TAB completion **working** for PPTP networks on any other Linux distro I tested.

Does anybody knows what change should be done to **enable TAB completion**?

**Further Data**:

- Tested (not working) on **Kali** Linux v2 and **Ubuntu** Mint v16.04.1 LTS .
- **Bash completion** seems to be working OK for the usual keywords. Package `bash-completion` is installed and updated, according to `apt-get`.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/33440/tab-completion-doesnt-work-for-commands ?

Comment: also, you can make it work on your own :) locations can, of course, differ a bit http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134892/is-there-a-way-to-customize-programmable-completion-in-the-current-session